# Reducing one variant of Hamiltonian path to another

Tags: computability, reductions, hamiltonian-path

Define

$A = \{<G,s,t> :G$  is un directed graph that has a Hamilton path from $s$ to $t\}$

$B = \{<G> :G$  is un directed graph that has a Hamilton path$\}$

I would like to show that $A \le_p B$.

My attempt:

Given $<G,s,t>$ , the reduction outputs $<G'>$ where $G'$ defines as follows:

we take $v_s$ and $v_t$ s.t there is an edge $e_s$ between $s$ and$v_s$ and an edge $e_t$ between $v_t$ and $t$.

Now we define $G' = (V',E')$ where $V' = V \cup \{v_0 , v_1\}$ and $E' = (E-\{e' :e' \ne e_s , s\in e'\} -\{e' :e' \ne e_t , t\in e'\}) \cup \{ \{v_0,v \} :\{v,s\} \in E \} \cup  \{ \{v_1,v \} :\{v,t\} \in E \} \cup \{ \{v_0,s \}\ , \{v_1,t\} \}$.

Now, if $<G,s,t> \in A$  , let $s , u_1,\dots ,u_n ,t$ be the Hamilton path , then $s , v_0 , u_1 , \dots , u_n, v_1 ,t$ is a Hamilton path in $G'$.

The other direction does not work for me , if $G'$ has a Hamilton path then I want to say that the "end points" must be around $s,t$ but i'm not sure how to do that.

Comment: The title you have chosen is not well suited to representing your question. Please take some time to improve it; we have collected some advice [here](http://meta.cs.stackexchange.com/a/815/). Thank you!

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: @Raphael if this reduction works, im stuck on proving the other direction, if it doesn't i would like to know what would work.

Comment: We're happy to help you understand the concepts but just solving exercises for you is unlikely to achieve that. You might find [this page](https://cs.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1284/755) helpful in improving your question.  The purpose of this kind of exercise is for you to get practice with reductions; we don't need the practice, and if we solved it for you, you wouldn't get the benefit of practice.  We've written lots about reductions on this site -- see [tag:reductions], or look at some examples in a textbook on the subject.

Comment: @D.W. sorry but i dont get you. i did not look for an easy way. i tried to solve it alone, and got stuck in the middle , and asked for some guidance. i am familiar with some reductions, this one just dont work for me.

Comment: @YuvalFilmus Nice! Can't believe i did not thought about it. i made it so hard. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest reduction, which is similar to what you were trying but simpler, is to add two new vertices to the graph in the instance of A: a vertex $v_s$ connected to $s$, and a vertex $v_t$ connected to $t$. Any Hamiltonian path in the new graph will connect $v_s$ to $v_t$, and so will restrict to a Hamiltonian path connecting $s$ to $t$. Vice versa, any Hamiltonian path in the original graph connecting $s$ to $t$ extends to a Hamiltonian path in the new graph connecting $v_s$ to $v_t$.